# @type/node error: Angular 4 on SystemJS with systemjs-builder

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, systemjs-builder

### Update: it's work again without fixed

I look https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node, they had updated, my project is FAIL.

7 days ago, it's work and build test on Travis

https://travis-ci.org/AngularVN/angular4-seed/jobs/235774520[image]

Now, It's have a major issue, help me
[image]

I'm try again with my laptop, it's fail. Maybe it's problem with typescript compiler.

I think this is problem of dependencies, someone was updated and crashed everything

```
ubuntu 16.04 x64
node 6.10.3
npm 3.10.10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the @types packages. For me, it was @types/node conflicting with @types/core-js.

I suspect you have something like this in your package.json file

`"@types/node": "^6.0.58",
 "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",`

Try changing it to a specific version, for example, these are the versions which are currently working for me

`"@types/node": "6.0.58",
 "@types/core-js": "0.9.35",`